# mysql select all from table but change column name of only one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to select a table which contains id, name and some more. Now i want to select everything, but just change the column name 'name' to 'user_name'. How can i do this without selecting and declaring everything? 
I tried it like this, but this is not working.

```
return $query
->select(
  'user.*',
  'user.name as user_name'
)
```

Comment: How do you mean it's not working? Do you get an error or something else?

Comment: Also, can you try `return $query->select(['user.name as user_name', 'user.*'])`

Comment: the point is, that i am left joining it with the same table but on an other user. So both have the column 'name'. Therefore it overrwirte the previous dump. The id also gets overwritten but i dont need it anyway.

Comment: Why you don't use the eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue starts from your joins. Because you join without aliasing, then the second one overwrites the first. I give you a sample query to show how you can alias your joined table, and thus alias the 'name' from the second table. Sample code:

```
$query = DB::table('users')
->leftjoin('users as child', 'users.id', '=', 'users.parent_id')
->select('users.*', 'child.name as child_name')
->get();
```